# VBA find matching headername and rowname in separate sheets

Tags: vba, excel

It's been a while since my last VBA explorations and I have googled around for a couple of hours now without any specific luck I am afraid.

I have 2 sheets.

**TargetSheet**

```
      2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 ...  
RowX  
RowY
```

**Data**

```
      2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 ...           
RowX
RowY
```

I am looking for a way to first search for matching `HeaderName` between `TargetSheet` and `Data`, `2008` etc and then matching Row Names, `RowX` etc.

When I find a matching header name and row name I want to print the value that is found in `Data` to `TargetSheet`.

I have not gotten very far unfortunately but what I have found and started editing is this below. I can find my values in sheet `Data` but the rest I don't really know how to sort out. Maybe some of you can help point me in the right direction? My code is pretty much crap at the moment.

```
Sub match()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Data")
        lastxvar = .Range("C1").End(xlToRight).Column

        For i = 3 To lastxvar
            Debug.Print lastxvar

            x = .Cells(1, i).value
            Debug.Print x

            findcol = 0

            On Error Resume Next
            '(LastxVar2) Tried Specifing what range i want to look for value X in (Dosnt seem to work).
            LastxVar2 = TargetSheet.Range("B1").End(xlToRight).Column

            findcol = Application.match(x, Worksheets("´TargetSheet").LastxVar2)
            findcol2 = Application.match(x, Worksheets("Data").x, 0)
            Debug.Print findcol
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not IsError(findcol) Then
                ' If value X is found in Range LastxVar2 then print Value in coresponding row match to TargetSheet
                .Cells(1, i).Copy Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, findcol)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank u Alex P for the edited version! Sloopy of me. How did u do to add the nicer looking tables?

Comment: I normally use this site: [https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: From your example it looks as if all the headers match. I think you could do this with Index and Match formulae rather than VBA.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you @SJR